# Good training for IDAPython

Tags: ida, idapython, python

I'm familiar with python and IDA in general.  I found a few very basic tutorials but nothing that goes through an explanation of the classes used and the full capability set.  Near as I can tell the documentation consists of a list of functions.  The IDAPro book just recommends learning it through banging your head against a wall.

Anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wrote [Sark](https://github.com/tmr232/Sark) to avoid this banging-head-against-wall routine. It provides wrappers around most of the commonly-used IDAPython APIs, making them more pythonic.
You can find the documentation for Sark [here on Read-The-Docs](http://sark.readthedocs.org/).

As mentioned before by @CrazyFrog, you can use:

1. Alexander Hanel's [book](https://leanpub.com/IDAPython-Book) and [blog](http://hooked-on-mnemonics.blogspot.com/);
2. Ero Carrera's [Intro to IDAPyton](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/11);

Additionally, there are official Hex-Rays sources:

1. [IDAPython Examples](https://github.com/idapython/src/tree/master/examples), which is filled with useful snippets;
2. [IDAPython Docs](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/), which are not too useful;
3. The IDA SDK headers (or the [SDK Docs](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/sdkdoc/)). This is a really useful source of information, as `grep`ing through it will usually get you the function you were looking for.
4. [Hex-Blog](http://www.hexblog.com/) - The Hex-Rays blog. Contains some neat tricks along with tutorials on new APIs.

Answer (score 6):

Check out "[The Beginner's Guide to IDAPython](https://leanpub.com/IDAPython-Book)" by Alexander Hanel and his [blog](http://hooked-on-mnemonics.blogspot.com/)

and this by [Ero Carrera](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/11)